# Xcode Shell Script error exit code 2

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, ios11, xcode9

I recently migrated to Xcode 9 and I'm trying to compile my project in iOS 11. I'm getting the following after I did "pod install" and "pod update" to my frameworks. Does any one know how to fix it?

> Code Signing /Users/XXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-ctuqdlicbgzykkgkzocyagspzqch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/'.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework with Identity -
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements   '/Users/XXXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXX-ctuqdlicbgzykkgkzocyagspzqch/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/'.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework'
>   /Users/venkateshchathalavada/Documents/IOSWorkspace/cloudoffers-app/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-'/Pods-'-frameworks.sh: eval: line 68: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
>   Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Comment: Please include your shell script. The error message is very clear: You have an opening backtick which is not closed. That's in some line between 1 and 68.

Comment: Solved - The problem was the target was using default name of ', renaming the target solved the issue.